# Trouble for rendering a simple checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, boolean

I try to render a simple checkbox (a boolean checkbox) in Django.

**form.py**

```
class Stateform(forms.Form):
     state = forms.BooleanField()
```

**html**

```
<form "..." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="checkbox">  
<label>{{ form }}</label>
</input>
</form>
```

**view.py**

```
def Defstate(request, *args):

  if request.method =='POST':
      form = Stateform(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
            ...
  else :
      form = Stateform()
  context = {
      'form': Stateform(),
      }
return render(request, 'Page1/Page3.html', context)
```

It display the checkbox correctly but it's impossible for me to check the box...

Comment: looks like you have to add a widget to your forms field

Comment: Normaly a Booleanfield form get the CheckboxInput widget by default

Comment: can you provide your view.py?

Comment: View.py add to the question

Comment: Could it be that in your `view.py` you imported `Form` from `django.forms` instead from your form.py?

Comment: I have check but it's good.... `from .forms import Form`

Comment: When the file is called `form.py` using `from  .forms import Form` should be wrong... You really should not call it just `Form`

Comment: Ok, I change Form to stateform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem!

When you use `<label>` you must define an id and it should be same as `<input>`.

Like :

```
<input id="id_1" type="checkbox">
<label for="id_1">
{{ form }}
</label> </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following html code:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also the naming of `Form` is somehow not very specific and is maybe misleading with the `Form` from `django.forms` which would render as empty form when used.

Comment: No, I have already try... {{form}} should return all the content of Form ?

Comment: Ok, fixed my answer for that request

Comment: In this case, nothing is display (I don't have put the <form></form> code in my question, sorry...